# How can I tell if a Meteor publication exists?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Is there some way to tell from the client if the server does indeed have a publication that the client would like to subscribe to?

This would help diagnose incorrect subscription names that are supplied by the user to a package like [autocomplete](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete).

Comment: Have you investigated the `onError` callback you can pass when you initiate the subscription?